# Count how many times an element occurs in an array via .reduce in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am new to JS. I am stuck at `.reduce`

I want to count the occurrence of a specific element in an array, I can do it via `for` loop but I can't get it done via `.reduce` method. Your help would be highly appreciated.

`let array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,98,-546,4]`

result should be something like `1 -> 4` times ; `2 -> 4` times etc..

How to do it in reduce high order function ?

Comment: You should add your code for your normal loop, and your attempts at using `reduce` to your question as [mcve]s. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: If you want to count the occurrence specific number you can use something like this 
`arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr == _[Your Number]_ ? acc++ : 0, acc) , 0);`

Answer (score 1):

That would do the job:

```
let occurenciesMap = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc[curr]) acc[curr] = 0; // As default start to count from 0
    acc[curr] += 1;
    return acc;
}, {})
```

Returns:

```
{
  '1': 4,
  '2': 4,
  '3': 8,
  '4': 3,
  '5': 1,
  '6': 1,
  '7': 1,
  '98': 1,
  '-546': 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,98,-546,4];

const res = array.reduce((accumulator, currentNumber) => {
  (accumulator[currentNumber]) ?
    accumulator[currentNumber]++ : accumulator[currentNumber] = 1
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```